# Rails respond to JSON extremely slow on Heroku

Tags: json, ruby-on-rails

**I'm using a JSON response in my controller:**

```
respond_to do |format|
    format.json {render json: [products: @products, boxes: @boxes,categories: @categories, giftpacks: @giftpacks,extras: @extras,user: @user,kits: @kits]}
end
```

**In my local server, I'm getting this time load:**

[image]

**When deployed to Heroku, I'm getting this time load and a 2.4MB file:**

[image]

¿How can I speed up things? This is so annoying.

Thanks!

Comment: use rails 7 with turbo-links https://hotwired.dev/#screencast

Comment: Well I guess your production database is much bigger than your local database. Which explains the difference.

Comment: @Maxence same DDBB, server response time is 12segs.... Activerecord only 0.5ms

Comment: @user3074558 so the response is exactly the same? Can you provide any additional details other than your experienced response times? Please realize that Heroku dynos have RAM limitations as well as if you are using the Free version (they go to sleep).